# Working with performance on requests Parse SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-server

I'm having some performance issues with my Parse queries, using Parse SDK.

On some requests, I have to get a ressources related to another one. E.g. :

- I get all elements from ClassA
- foreach ClassA elements, I have to find all ClassB and ClassC elements which contain a pointer to the relevant entry in ClassA.

Right now, to sum up:

- I query all my ClassA elements
- I loop on the results, and create a Promise (Parse query) to get ClassB elements and another one (Parse query) to get ClassC elements foreach result

My issue is that solution makes a lot of Parse Query, so a lot of Promise that I have to wait for. **The real issue is that on my local env, all is working fine, the whole request makes 1s or less** (it's quite heavy, but it does 45 parse query in the current case - based on my Class entries).
**On my production server, same code, same data, same Node version, the same request makes 30s or more (=> timeout)**.

This is the relevant part of the code (it's old and messy) :

```
router.get('/:userId/company/customers', (req, res, next) => {
  if('company' in req.jwtData.data) {
    const company = req.jwtData.data.company;
    const query = new Parse.Query('Cards');
    const Companies = Parse.Object.extend('Companies');
    const currentCompany = new Companies({id: company.objectId});
    query.equalTo('company', currentCompany).find().then((cards) => {
      if(cards.length){
        const customersArrayId = cards.map(card => card.toJSON().user.objectId);
        const usersQuery = new Parse.Query('_User').containedIn('objectId', customersArrayId).find({ useMasterKey: true });
        usersQuery.then(customersResponse => {
          const customers = [];
          const customersPromises = [];
          if(customersResponse.length) {
            for (let index = 0; index < customersResponse.length; index++) {
              let customer = {
                ...customersResponse[index].toJSON(),
                ...customersResponse[index].attributes
              }; 
              const customerPromises = [];
              const customerId = customer.objectId;
              const stamps = new Parse.Query('Stamps').equalTo('user', new UserModel({objectId: customerId})).equalTo('company', currentCompany).limit(CONSTANTS.QUERY_MAX_LIMIT).find().then((stamps) => {
                return stamps;
              }).catch(error => {
                res.json({
                  success: false,
                  error
                });
              });
              const cards = new Parse.Query('Cards').equalTo('user', new UserModel({objectId: customerId})).equalTo('company', currentCompany).limit(CONSTANTS.QUERY_MAX_LIMIT).find().then((cards) => {
                return cards;
              }).catch(error => {
                res.json({
                  success: false,
                  error
                });
              });
              customers.push(customer);
              customerPromises.push(stamps);
              customerPromises.push(cards);
              customersPromises.push(customerPromises);
            }
            if(customersPromises.length) {
              const allPromises = customersPromises.map(customerP => Promise.all(customerP));
              Promise.all(allPromises).then((customerPromiseResponses) => {  
                console.log('allPromises done, mapping all users data...');
                for (let index = 0; index < customerPromiseResponses.length; index++) {                  
                  const customerResponseData = customerPromiseResponses[index];
                  const stamps = customerResponseData[0];
                  const cards = customerResponseData[1];
                  const companyEmailAllowed = () => {
                    let check = false;
                    if(customers[index].hasOwnProperty('companiesNewsletterAgreements')) {
                      check = customers[index].companiesNewsletterAgreements.indexOf(company.objectId) > -1;
                    }
                    return check;
                  };
                  customers[index] = {
                    ...customers[index],
                    email: companyEmailAllowed() ? customers[index].email : null,
                    stamps,
                    cards,
                  }
                }                
                res.json({
                  success: true,
                  data: customers
                });
              }).catch(error => {
                res.json({
                  success: false,
                  error
                });
              });
            }
            else {
              res.json({
                success: true,
                data: customers
              });
            }

          } else {
            res.json({
              success: true,
              data: customers
            });
          }



        });
      } else {
        res.json({
          success: true,
          data: []
        });
      }


    });
  } else {
    res.json({
      success: false,
      error: "No company found."
    });
  }
});
```

**My question is: is it possible to get the same data in a more performant way (less Parse queries, less Promises)?**

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution. Instead of starting Parse query for each result I found, I request the whole set of elements I need in the first place, using `containedIn`.

Then, I filter the results to assign the elements to their customer.